# Change Class-Binded Shadow Colour WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, styling, shadow

I was looking on how to replicate a Google button's shadow on hover effect in my WPF document and came across this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53031057/12299798, which answers my problem exactly, but the only issue I have is that I normally do all the frontend things in XAML and so I am not quite experienced in the styling in C#. My problem is that I want to 'Bind' my foreground colour to the shadow colour, this is because in the code it only sets it to a greyish colour which would mean I would have to do a whole other class for each colour that I want to set it for. Here is my code now:

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Button Content="shadow">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="local:UI.Elevation" Value="10"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="local:UI.Elevation" Value="0"/>

                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

UI.cs:

```
public static class UI
{

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ElevationProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Elevation", typeof(double), typeof(UI), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(double), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, null, OnRedElevationChanged));

    public static double GetElevation(this UIElement element) => element.GetValue(ElevationProperty) as double? ?? default;

    public static void SetElevation(this UIElement element, double elevation) => element.SetValue(ElevationProperty, elevation);

    private static object OnRedElevationChanged(DependencyObject d, object value)
    {
        if (d is UIElement element && value is double elevation)
            if (elevation == 0)
                element.Effect = null;
            else
            {
                Effect e = CreateElevation(elevation, element.Effect);
                if (e != null)
                    element.Effect = e;
            }
        return value;
    }

    private static Effect CreateElevation(double elevation, Effect source)
    {
        void MixShadows(DropShadowEffect nearest, DropShadowEffect matched, double balance)
        {
            matched.BlurRadius = matched.BlurRadius * (1 - balance) + nearest.BlurRadius * balance;
            matched.ShadowDepth = matched.ShadowDepth * (1 - balance) + nearest.ShadowDepth * balance;
        }
        DropShadowEffect[] shadows = new DropShadowEffect[]
        {
        new DropShadowEffect()
        {
            BlurRadius = 5,
            ShadowDepth = 1
        },
        new DropShadowEffect()
        {
            BlurRadius = 8,
            ShadowDepth = 1.5
        },
        new DropShadowEffect()
        {
            BlurRadius = 14,
            ShadowDepth = 4.5
        },
        new DropShadowEffect()
        {
            BlurRadius = 25,
            ShadowDepth = 8
        },
        new DropShadowEffect()
        {
            BlurRadius = 35,
            ShadowDepth = 13
        }
        };
        elevation = Math.Max(0, elevation / 12 * shadows.Length - 1);
        int prevIndex = (int)Math.Floor(elevation), index = (int)elevation, nextIndex = (int)Math.Ceiling(elevation);
        double approx = elevation - index;
        DropShadowEffect shadow = shadows[index];
        if (approx != 0)
            MixShadows(approx < 0 ? shadows[prevIndex] : shadows[nextIndex], shadow, Math.Abs(approx));
        bool modify = false;
        if (source is DropShadowEffect sourceShadow)
        {
            sourceShadow.BlurRadius = shadow.BlurRadius;
            sourceShadow.ShadowDepth = shadow.ShadowDepth;
            shadow = sourceShadow;
            modify = true;
        }
        shadow.Direction = 270;
        shadow.Color = Colors.Red;
        shadow.Opacity = .42;
        shadow.RenderingBias = RenderingBias.Performance;
        return modify ? null : shadow;
    }
}
```

And to get what I want in XAML I would do something like this:

```
<Button Content="shadow">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="local:UI.Elevation" Value="10"/>
                        <Setter Property="local:UI.Elevation.Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="local:UI.Elevation" Value="0"/>
                        <Setter Property="local:UI.Elevation.Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

But I don't quite know how to link up the `local:UI.Elevation.Foreground` to change the shadow colour, I would have to change this line here from `UI.cs`: `shadow.Color = Colors.Red;` and bind it to the Elevation.Foreground, but I am having difficulties. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is updated the UI class with a new attached property named something like `Color` of type `Color` and give it a default color you like.

Then, in its `OnColorChanged` handler, call `OnElevationChanged` so that the shadow gets recreated.

```
#region Color (Attached Property)
public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "Color",
        typeof(Color),
        typeof(UI),
        new PropertyMetadata(Colors.Black, OnColorChanged));

public static Color GetColor(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (Color)obj.GetValue(ColorProperty);
}

public static void SetColor(DependencyObject obj, Color value)
{
    obj.SetValue(ColorProperty, value);
}

private static void OnColorChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    OnElevationChanged(d, GetElevation((UIElement)d));
}
#endregion
```

In the `CreateElevation` method, add a new parameter for the color, so you can set it.

```
private static Effect CreateElevation(double elevation, Effect source, Color color)
{
    ...
    shadow.Color = color;
    ...
}
```

Finally, in `OnElevationChanged` update it so it to call `GetColor` so it can pass in the new `Color` property.

```
private static object OnElevationChanged(DependencyObject d, object value)
{
    if (d is UIElement element && value is double elevation)
        if (elevation == 0)
            element.Effect = null;
        else
        {
            Effect e = CreateElevation(elevation, element.Effect, GetColor(element));
            if (e != null)
                element.Effect = e;
        }
    return value;
}
```

Example XAML

```
<Button
    Width="100"
    Height="20"
    Content="shadow">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="local:UI.Elevation" Value="10" />
                    <Setter Property="local:UI.Color" Value="Blue" />
                </Trigger>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="local:UI.Elevation" Value="5" />
                    <Setter Property="local:UI.Color" Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

**NOTE**: There is some refactoring you could do to make all this cleaner, but hopefully this will get your started.

Comment: So I made a ```DependencyProperty ColourProperty``` and a ```OnColourChanged``` event but I don't understand how I then send it to the ```OnElevationChanged```, where I can then send it to ```CreateElevation```

Comment: I updated my answer with working code. You should probably invest some time into learning about how attached properties work. That will help you understand the code much better. You can do a lot with attached properties/behaviors! :)

Comment: Works great and as expected! Will be sure to look into attached properties and more frontend design in general using C#. Thanks again!